# Remove dynamically added LI list item with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to dynamically add a list item to a list and then remove it by clicking on that item.  The remove event never seems to fire.  However if I use the same code on a static list it works fine.  I've seen similar solutions but they do not work.

See jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lc2bC/

```
<input id="status" type="text" placeholder="Status (tab or enter)">

<br/>
Dynamic List:
<ul id="statusList"></ul> 


$('#status').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 9 || e.which == 13) {
        $('#statusList').html($('#statusList').html() + formatNewStatus(this.value));
        this.value = "";
        this.focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});

$(function () {
    $('#statusList li').click(function () {
        alert('dynamicList');
        $(this).remove();
    })
});
```

Comment: You have to use delegation with on()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the `click()` function only binds to elements that exist in the dom at the time it is called.

`live()` is the older technique, but is deprecated and will not be supported in future versions.

What you need to use is [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#statusList').on('click', 'li', function () {
        alert('dynamicList');
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: `live()` is not even supported in current versions -- it was removed in jQuery 1.9. Why would you even bother mentioning it, since the question never asked about it?

Comment: All accurate information is helpful, especially for people like me who are in and out of jQuery.  I didn't realize that on() replaced live(), as I don't do a lot of jquery.  I actually tried to use live() at some point.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

The `click` function only binds to elements that were present when it was called.  Use `on()` instead.

> **on()**
>
> Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: `live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, removed in 1.9. You mean `on()`.

Comment: Good catch, updated.  I'm still working on an old jQuery code base.  Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use on http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(function () {
    $('#statusList').on("click", "li", function () {
        alert('dynamicList');
        $(this).remove();
    })
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lc2bC/2/)

Comment: Correct as well.  Thanks for making use of the fiddle too.